# Saving a hash literal (telling Rails not to interpret hash as a nested attribute)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I think Rails is interpreting my hash literal as a nested attribute. I would actually just like to convert the hash to a string. It's not a nested attribute related to some model, nor should it be related to a model. Here, nesting the values is merely a convenient way to pass data through a form without too much busywork.

:params was

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"[deleted for SO]",
 "scorecard"=>{"1"=>"2",
 "2"=>"2",
 "3"=>"2",
 "4"=>"2",
 "5"=>"2",
 "6"=>"2",
 "7"=>"2",
 "8"=>"2",
 "9"=>"2",
 "10"=>"2",
 "11"=>"2",
 "12"=>"2"}},
 "commit"=>"Create Assessment"}
```

.. but when I do:

```
assessment = Assessment.new(params[:assessment])
...
@assessment.save
```

... I get:

```
unknown attribute: scorecard
```

Interestingly, when

```
attr_accessible :scorecards
```

.. is in the model (note plural form), I get:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: scorecard
```

Since when attr_accessible is what I actually want (:scorecard), I get "unknown attribute: scorecard", it seems Rails thinks it's dealing with a nested attribute.

Can I tell Rails not to treat :scorecard as a nested attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean to leave out the *'s'* in attr_accessible?

```
attr_accessible :scorecard(s)
```

**EDIT**

you many be getting this next error because you are missing a `scorecard` column on your table

```
unknown attribute: scorecard
```

Comment: also, to store the hash as a string, declare `serialize :scorecard` in your model.

Comment: Yes, I did mean to leave it out. That leads to "Can't mass-sign protected attributes: scorecard" (with no 's'). Changing adding 's' to the param name on the web page will then require attr_accessible to be scorecarddss, with two s's on the end.

Doing "serialize: scorecard" in the model didn't seem to do the trick (even though I'd expect it to); I still get 'unknown attribute: scorecard'.

Comment: s/That leads to/Adding the 's' in attr_accessible leads to

Comment: can you post your model and controller?

Comment: I was in fact missing the column. Thanks.. new to Rails and didn't realize my migration hadn't updated my schema.

Comment: hey no problem, dont be discouraged tho, Rails is full of gotchas, but you'll probably get the hang of it with some practice.  I've definitely had this same problem before and thought 'wtf i dont get it' and spent way too much time figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your column names of the table? It seems that you are missing the column 'scorecard'. Or did you name it as 'scorecards' ? Just in case.

Also you have to declare serialized :scorecard to save a serialized value. Saving it as a JSON is also an option. Just need additional parsing.